# Issue with updating moderation status from rest api

Tags: sharepoint-online, microsoft-graph

I'm trying to update the moderation status of a sharepoint file through rest API. The rest API will be called from java code.I'm trying to update it using a HTTP patch request for graph api.I'm using the below API

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/{site}/drives/{driveId}/items/{itenId}/listitem
```

and my payload is

```
{  
    "_ModerationStatus" : 0  
}
```

The status is getting updated but it reverts back to pending as a new version is created.

I have versioning turned on my document library. Is there any way to update the moderation status without it rolling back to pending.

> **Note:**I need versioning on my library. So, the versioning setting cannot be turned off.

Comment: If an item is modified after it has been approved it's moderation status **Should** revert back, as it is no longer the version that was approved.

Comment: Is there any way to approve the file using the Graph API? Since we are only updating the moderation status, the revert back beats the purpose.

Comment: The Graph API does not directly support Approving items yet, but your can try an old SP-server technique of sending `OData__ModerationStatus` instead of `_ModerationStatus`.

Comment: I tried sending OData__ModerationStatus : 0 in body, but that didn't work.It still gets reverted back to Pending. Am I doing something wrong here.

Comment: Are you saving the item more than once?  As previously mentioned, if you modify an item after it is approved, it should change back to pending.

Comment: I have a document which is in pending state initially and I'm trying to update the status using Rest API to Approved. I'm not saving it twice I'm using the patch request to update the moderationStatus field of the listItem.
But each time I call this patch request a new version is created for the item instead of  just updating the status column of existing version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Graph API doesn't have an exact equivalent, but the SharePoint REST API specifically has an Approve method on the File object:  https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/sharepoint-rest-reference/dn450841(v%3doffice.15)#approve